How to observe changes in a List when the ViewModel is in Java and the UI is in Jetpack Compose (Kotlin)
I am migrating an application from View to Compose. The application was written in Java so I need to migrate the UI to Kotlin.
I prefer to do it as gradually as possible so I'm leaving the ViewModel in Java.
The UI is a lazy column of Cards. A long click on a card toggles its selected state. It sends an event to the ViewModel - adding/deleting its ID to/from a List that contains the IDs of the selected cards.
I would like the UI to observe the changes in the List of IDs.
Currently, I use a workaround: An observable Boolean that toggles with every change in the List of IDs. I wonder if there is a better approach.
Some code:
The UI part - The function that displays the card:
    @OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
    @Composable
    private fun DisplayAlarmItem(alarmItem: AlarmItem) {

        // Force this function to be called when list of selected changes
        val selectToggle by parent!!.alarmViewModel.selectToggleObserve.observeAsState( )
        val toggled = if (selectToggle!=null && selectToggle as Boolean) "A" else "B"

        // Get list of selected alarms and mark this item as selected(yes/no)
        val selectedAlarmList by parent!!.alarmViewModel.selectedItems.observeAsState()
        val filterList = selectedAlarmList?.filter {  it.equals(alarmItem.createTime.toInt()) }
        var selected= (filterList != null && filterList.isNotEmpty())
        val backgroundColor = if (selected) MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceVariant else MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface


        val currentAlpha = if (alarmItem.isActive) 1.0f else 0.3f
        Card(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(5.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .combinedClickable(
                    onLongClick = { AlarmItemLongClicked(alarmItem.getCreateTime()) },
                    onClickLabel = "Edit Alarm"
                )
                { AlarmItemEdit(alarmItem, true) }
                .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface)
                .wrapContentHeight(),
            shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
            elevation = CardDefaults.elevatedCardElevation(5.dp),
            colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(containerColor = backgroundColor),
            
            ) {
                ConstraintLayout(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                    val refLabel = createRef()
                    val refBell = createRef()
                    val refAlarmTime = createRef()
                    val refAlarmActive = createRef()
                    val refAmPm24h = createRef()
                    val refWeekdays = createRef()

               }
            }
    }

Now, The Long Click callback:
    private fun AlarmItemLongClicked(id: Long) {
    // get the list of alarms
    //List<AlarmItem> alarmItems = parent.alarmViewModel.getAlarmList().getValue();
    //if (alarmItems==null) return;

    // Update the list of the selected items - simply toggle
    parent!!.alarmViewModel.toggleSelection(id)

    // Modify toolbar according to number of selected items
    parent!!.UpdateOptionMenu()

    // Inform the ViewModel that the selection List was changed
    parent?.alarmViewModel?.selectToggleObserve()
}

On the ViewModel, the code that adds/removes ID from the List of selected IDs:
   public void toggleSelection(long id){
  int index = selectedItems.indexOf((int)id);
  if (index >=0)
     selectedItems.remove(index);
  else
     selectedItems.add((int)id);

  LiveSelectedItems.setValue(selectedItems);
  selectToggleObserve();

}
The definitions of the above properties:
private final MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Integer>> LiveSelectedItems;
private final ArrayList<Integer> selectedItems;


State needs to know when its value has been updated, but it can not track changes in a List. To trigger State update you need to create a new collection instance instead of updating the LiveData with the same instance of ArrayList.
View model:
private final MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Integer>> liveSelectedItems = new MutableLiveData<>(new ArrayList<>());
public final LiveData<ArrayList<Integer>> selectedItems = liveSelectedItems;

public void toggleSelection(int id) {
    var currentList = Objects.requireNonNull(liveSelectedItems.getValue());
    var newList = new ArrayList<>(currentList);
    int index = currentList.indexOf(id);
    if (index >= 0) {
        newList.remove(index);
    } else {
        newList.add(id);
    }
    liveSelectedItems.setValue(newList);
}

Sample composable:
val selectedItems by viewModel.selectedItems.observeAsState(ArrayList())
Column {
    repeat(10) { index ->
        Card(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(5.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .clickable { viewModel.toggleSelection(index) },
        ) {
            Text("Item $index selected: ${selectedItems.contains(index)}")
        }
    }
}


Fantastic. It works. Thanks a lot!
However, I have a couple of questions: 1. Why expose a LiveData version of liveSelectedItems, isn't it possible to observe a MutableLiveData variable?
2. Why do I need both newList AND currentList ?


It is possible, but it's generally a good idea to make everything as immutable as possible, so to avoid updates from other classes it is better to expose LiveData Also see. 2. You only need the old list to initialize a new one. @Shaul

